# How to align lines inside Text widget with grid rows outside the widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

I have a tkinter frame with many rows. Each row has some labels and an entry widget placed with the `widget.grid()` function. In the last column I want to place a Text widget, in which each line coincides with each grid row outside the Text widget, i.e., the lines in the Text widget should be aligned with the other widgets.

For now I just used `text.grid(row=1, column=5, rowspan=rw)` where `rw` is the number of rows, and I tried adjusting the line spacings with `text.config(spacing1=...)`, `text.config(spacing2=...)` and `text.config(spacing3=...)`. However, adjusting the line spacings for some reason messes up with the row spacing outside the text widget - as I increase the line spacing in the text widget, the padding of the outside rows also seems to increase.

The reason I'm doing this is that I want the last column to be scrollable horizontally, and this seemed shorter/easier than placing a canvas and adding the labels and scrollbar to it. If you have other ideas for how to achieve this I'll be glad to hear them.

Answer (score -1):

> Each row has some labels and an entry widget placed with the
> widget.grid() function. In the last column I want to place a Text
> widget, in which each line coincides with each grid row outside the
> Text widget, i.e., the lines in the Text widget should be aligned with
> the other widgets.

The problem can be fix.

- Add three widgets `Label`, `Entry` and `Text`.
- Create `list` for number of `Label`
- Iterate through list using  `range` and `len()`.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

root =tk.Tk()

data = ['Label 1', 'Label 2','Label 3', 'Label 4','Label 5', 'Label 6']

ipadding = {'padx': 2}
 
for i in range(len(data)):
    #for x in range(1, 5):
    t = tk.Label(root, text=data[i])
     
    e = tk.Entry(root)

    text = tk.Entry(root)
    text.grid(row=i, column=2, **ipadding)
    e.grid(row=i, column=1, **ipadding)
    t.grid(row=i, padx=5)
 
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]